# Add characters counter to wordpress title and excerpt

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I want to create a counter at the bottom of the fields post title and post excerpt, but when the user exceed the limit, he should get just an alert ("You put more characters then recommended!"), he can decide to ignore the alert and keep typing.

Didn't find any solution in the web that match my requirements.

Comment: 1. have to register js file for the specific post type you want this validation.
2. Write the js code onkeyup and perform the valiadtions. By using the title field ID

Answer (score 0):

Open functions.php file in your theme’s directory and paste at the end the code from below:

```
<?php function my_title_count(){ ?>
<script>jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#titlediv .inside").after("<div style=\"position:absolute;top:40px;right:-5px;\"><span>Max 70 characters:</span> <input type=\"text\" value=\"0\" maxlength=\"3\" size=\"3\" id=\"title_counter\" readonly=\"\" style=\"background:none;border:none;box-shadow:none;font-weight:bold; text-align:right;\"></div>");
jQuery("#title_counter").val(jQuery("#title").val().length);
jQuery("#title").keyup( function() {
jQuery("#title_counter").val(jQuery("#title").val().length);
});
});
</script>
<? }
add_action( 'admin_head-post.php', 'my_title_count');
add_action( 'admin_head-post-new.php', 'my_title_count');
?>

<?php function my_excerpt_count(){ ?>
<script>jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery("#postexcerpt .handlediv").after("<div style=\"position:absolute;top:4px;right:25px;\"><span>Max 156 characters:</span> <input type=\"text\" value=\"0\" maxlength=\"3\" size=\"3\" id=\"excerpt_counter\" readonly=\"\" style=\"background:none;border:none;box-shadow:none;font-weight:bold; text-align:right;\"></div>");
jQuery("#excerpt_counter").val(jQuery("#excerpt").val().length);
jQuery("#excerpt").keyup( function() {
jQuery("#excerpt_counter").val(jQuery("#excerpt").val().length);
});
});
</script>
<? }
add_action( 'admin_head-post.php', 'my_excerpt_count');
add_action( 'admin_head-post-new.php', 'my_excerpt_count');
?>
```

Comment: There seem to be a couple of issues with the above code. Please have a look at a [most recent question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/247184/) on wordpress.stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

I found a pretty good and easy solution:
http://www.passwordincorrect.com/add-character-count-to-title-and-excerpt-in-wordpress-post-editor/

Now putting the alert message should be easy.
Enjoy!